# Spark / Scala: forward fill with last observation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.4.0, Scala 2.10

I've been trying to figure out a way to forward fill null values with the last known observation, but I don't see an easy way. I would think this is a pretty common thing to do, but can't find an example showing how to do this.

I see functions to forward fill NaN with a value, or lag / lead functions to fill or shift data by an offset, but nothing to pick up the last known value.

Looking online, I see lots of Q/A about the same thing in R, but not in Spark / Scala.

I was thinking about mapping over a date range, filter the NaNs out of the results and pick the last element but I guess I'm confused about the syntax.

Using DataFrames I try something like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

var spec = Window.orderBy("Date")
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("test.csv")

val df2 = df.withColumn("testForwardFill", (90 to 0).map(i=>lag(df.col("myValue"),i,0).over(spec)).filter(p=>p.getItem.isNotNull).last)
```

but that doesn't get me anywhere.

The filter part doesn't work; the map function returns a Sequence of spark.sql.Columns, but the filter function expects to return a Boolean, so I need to get a value out of the Column to test on but there only seem to be Column methods that return a Column.

Is there any way to do this more 'simply' on Spark?

Thanks for your input

**Edit**:

Simple example sample input:

```
2015-06-01,33
2015-06-02,
2015-06-03,
2015-06-04,
2015-06-05,22
2015-06-06,
2015-06-07,
...
```

Expected output:

```
2015-06-01,33
2015-06-02,33
2015-06-03,33
2015-06-04,33
2015-06-05,22
2015-06-06,22
2015-06-07,22
```

**Note**:

1. I have many columns, many of which have this missing data pattern, but not at the same date/time. If I need to I will do the transform one column at a time.

**EDIT**:

Following @zero323 's answer I tried this way:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

    val rows: RDD[Row] = df.orderBy($"Date").rdd


    def notMissing(row: Row): Boolean = { !row.isNullAt(1) }

    val toCarry: scala.collection.Map[Int,Option[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = rows.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
   case (i, iter) => Iterator((i, iter.filter(notMissing(_)).toSeq.lastOption)) }
.collectAsMap

    val toCarryBd = sc.broadcast(toCarry)

    def fill(i: Int, iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = { if (iter.contains(null)) iter.map(row => Row(toCarryBd.value(i).get(1))) else iter }

    val imputed: RDD[Row] = rows.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (i, iter) => fill(i, iter)}
```

the broadcast variable ends up as a list of values without nulls. That's progress but I still can't get the mapping to work.
but i get nothing, because the index `i` in the doesn't map to the original data, it maps to the subset without null.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT and solution (as infered from @zero323 's answer):**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

var spec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("Date")
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("test.csv")

val df2 = df.withColumn("test", coalesce((0 to 90).map(i=>lag(df.col("test"),i,0).over(spec)): _*))
```

See zero323's answer below for more options if you're using RDDs instead of DataFrames. The solution above may not be the most efficient but works for me. If you're looking to optimize, check out the RDD solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Initial answer (a single time series assumption):

First of all try avoid window functions if you cannot provide `PARTITION BY` clause. It moves data to a single partition so most of the time it is simply not feasible.

What you can do is to fill gaps on `RDD` using `mapPartitionsWithIndex`. Since you didn't provide an example data or expected output consider this to be pseudocode not a real Scala program:

- first lets order `DataFrame` by date and convert to `RDD`

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val rows: RDD[Row] = df.orderBy($"Date").rdd
  ```
- next lets find the last not null observation per partition

  ```
  def notMissing(row: Row): Boolean = ???

  val toCarry: scala.collection.Map[Int,Option[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = rows
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (i, iter) => 
      Iterator((i, iter.filter(notMissing(_)).toSeq.lastOption)) }
    .collectAsMap
  ```
- and convert this `Map` to broadcast

  ```
  val toCarryBd = sc.broadcast(toCarry)
  ```
- finally map over partitions once again filling the gaps:

  ```
  def fill(i: Int, iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
    // If it is the beginning of partition and value is missing
    // extract value to fill from toCarryBd.value
    // Remember to correct for empty / only missing partitions
    // otherwise take last not-null from the current partition
  }

  val imputed: RDD[Row] = rows
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (i, iter) => fill(i, iter) }
  ```
- finally convert back to DataFrame

### Edit (partitioned / time series per group data):

The devil is in the detail. If your data is partitioned after all then a whole problem can be solved using `groupBy`. Lets assume you simply partition by column "v" of type `T` and `Date` is an integer timestamp:

```
def fill(iter: List[Row]): List[Row] = {
  // Just go row by row and fill with last non-empty value
  ???
}

val groupedAndSorted = df.rdd
  .groupBy(_.getAs[T]("k"))
  .mapValues(_.toList.sortBy(_.getAs[Int]("Date")))

val rows: RDD[Row] = groupedAndSorted.mapValues(fill).values.flatMap(identity)

val dfFilled = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, df.schema)
```

This way you can fill all columns at the same time.

> Can this be done with DataFrames instead of converting back and forth to RDD?

It depends, although it is unlikely to be efficient. If maximum gap is relatively small you can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{WindowSpec, Window}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val maxGap: Int = ???  // Maximum gap between observations
val columnsToFill: List[String] = ???  // List of columns to fill
val suffix: String = "_" // To disambiguate between original and imputed 

// Take lag 1 to maxGap and coalesce
def makeCoalesce(w: WindowSpec)(magGap: Int)(suffix: String)(c: String) = {
  // Generate lag values between 1 and maxGap
  val lags = (1 to maxGap).map(lag(col(c), _)over(w))
  // Add current, coalesce and set alias
  coalesce(col(c) +: lags: _*).alias(s"$c$suffix")
}


// For each column you want to fill nulls apply makeCoalesce
val lags: List[Column] = columnsToFill.map(makeCoalesce(w)(maxGap)("_"))


// Finally select
val dfImputed = df.select($"*" :: lags: _*)
```

It can be easily adjusted to use different maximum gap per column.

A simpler way to achieve a similar result in the latest Spark version is to use `last` with `ignoreNulls`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"k").orderBy($"Date")
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df.withColumn("value", coalesce($"value", last($"value", true).over(w)))
```

While it is possible to drop `partitionBy` clause and apply this method globally, it would prohibitively expensive with large datasets.

Comment: Coalesce works for me. I just had to use (0 to maxGap) to include the current value, instead of 1 to maxGap

Comment: In the last method you could omit both `.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)` and the `coalesce` for same result.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do it only using Window function (without last function) and somehow clever partitionning. I personally really dislike having to use the combination of groupBy then further join.

So given:

```scala
date,      currency, rate
20190101   JPY       NULL
20190102   JPY       2
20190103   JPY       NULL
20190104   JPY       NULL
20190102   JPY       3
20190103   JPY       4
20190104   JPY       NULL
```

We can use Window.unboundedPreceding and Window.unboundedFollowing to create a key for forward and backward fill.

The following code:

```scala
val w1 = Window.partitionBy("currency").orderBy(asc("date"))
df
   .select("date", "currency", "rate")
   // Equivalent of fill.na(0, Seq("rate")) but can be more generic here
   // You may need an abs(col("rate")) if value col can be negative since it will not work with the following sums to build the forward and backward keys
   .withColumn("rate_filled", when(col("rate").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(col("rate")))
   .withColumn("rate_backsum",
     sum("rate_filled").over(w1.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))
   .withColumn("rate_forwardsum",
     sum("rate_filled").over(w1.rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)))
```

gives :

```scala
date,      currency, rate,  rate_filled, rate_backsum, rate_forwardsum
20190101   JPY       NULL             0             0             9
20190102   JPY       2                2             2             9
20190103   JPY       NULL             0             2             7
20190104   JPY       NULL             0             2             7
20190102   JPY       3                3             5             7
20190103   JPY       4                4             9             4
20190104   JPY       NULL             0             9             0
```

Therefore, we've built two keys (x_backsum and x_forwardsum) that can be used to ffill and bfill. With the two following spark lines :

```scala
val wb = Window.partitionBy("currency", "rate_backsum")
val wf = Window.partitionBy("currency", "rate_forwardsum")

   ...
   .withColumn("rate_backfilled", avg("rate").over(wb))
   .withColumn("rate_forwardfilled", avg("rate").over(wf))
```

Finally :

```scala
date,      currency, rate,   rate_backsum, rate_forwardsum, rate_ffilled
20190101   JPY       NULL               0               9              2
20190102   JPY       2                  2               9              2
20190103   JPY       NULL               2               7              3
20190104   JPY       NULL               2               7              3
20190102   JPY       3                  5               7              3
20190103   JPY       4                  9               4              4
20190104   JPY       NULL               9               0              0
```