# Join two data frames as input for Machine Learning with Spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, outer-join, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 data frames in Apache Spark, each with a column named "*JoinValue*". JoinValue is numeric and has the same semantics and meaning in both data frames.

I need the combination of both data frames as input (training and test set) for a Machine Learning algorithm. Is it correct that I first need to combine both DataFrames into a single DataFrame before using it in an ML Pipeline?

Example:

```
df1.show()
+---------+---------+
|        a|JoinValue|
+---------+---------+
|A value 0|        0|
|A value 1|        5|
|A value 2|       10|
|A value 3|       15|
|A value 4|       20|
|A value 5|       25|
|A value 6|       30|
+---------+---------+
```

and

```
> df2.show()
+---------+---------+
|        b|JoinValue|
+---------+---------+
|B value 0|        0|
|B value 1|        7|
|B value 2|       14|
|B value 3|       21|
|B value 4|       28|
+---------+---------+
```

An outer join followed by an `orderBy` yields the following results:

```
> df1.join(df2, 'JoinValue', 'outer').orderBy('JoinValue').show()
+---------+---------+---------+
|JoinValue|        a|        b|
+---------+---------+---------+
|        0|A value 0|B value 0|
|        5|A value 1|     null|
|        7|     null|B value 1|
|       10|A value 2|     null|
|       14|     null|B value 2|
|       15|A value 3|     null|
|       20|A value 4|     null|
|       21|     null|B value 3|
|       25|A value 5|     null|
|       28|     null|B value 4|
|       30|A value 6|     null|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I actually want is this, without `null`s:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|JoinValue|        a|        b|
+---------+---------+---------+
|        0|A value 0|B value 0|
|        5|A value 1|B value 0|
|        7|A value 1|B value 1|
|       10|A value 2|B value 1|
|       14|A value 2|B value 2|
|       15|A value 3|B value 2|
|       20|A value 4|B value 2|
|       21|A value 4|B value 3|
|       25|A value 5|B value 3|
|       28|A value 5|B value 4|
|       30|A value 6|B value 4|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

What is the best way to use the JoinValue, a and b, coming from multiple data frames as features and labels in a machine learning algorithm?

Comment: what you are asking for is not a standard join operation, I guess what you need is a followup forward fill (pandas ffill equivalent) .. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019847/pyspark-forward-fill-with-last-observation-for-a-dataframe) might help

Comment: Thanks, muon. I'll try the second answer: using [sparkts](http://sryza.github.io/spark-timeseries/0.3.0/index.html)