# Pyspark - how to backfill a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can you do the same thing as **[`df.fillna(method='bfill')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)** for a pandas dataframe with a **`pyspark.sql.DataFrame`**?

The pyspark dataframe has the [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) method, however there is no support for a `method` parameter.

---

In pandas you can use the following to backfill a time series:

**Create data**

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-05')
data = [1, 2, 3, None, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data}, index=index)
```

**Giving**

```
Out[1]:
            data
2017-01-01  1.0
2017-01-02  2.0
2017-01-03  3.0
2017-01-04  NaN
2017-01-05  5.0
```

**Backfill the dataframe**

```
df = df.fillna(method='bfill')
```

**Produces the backfilled frame**

```
Out[2]:
            data
2017-01-01  1.0
2017-01-02  2.0
2017-01-03  3.0
2017-01-04  5.0
2017-01-05  5.0
```

How can the same thing be done for a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`?

Comment: there is good info about forward fill in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019847/pyspark-forward-fill-with-last-observation-for-a-dataframe

Have a look at it.

Comment: I had the same problem, I converted the dataset to pandas DF, implemented the appropriate method (bfill...) then converted back to Spark DF. 
Before converting back to Spark though, I added a section to coerce each columns of my pandas DF in the appropriate data type. Spark can be picky on data type especially if you use a method such as 'interpolate', where you can end up with integer and float in the same column. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 6):

The `last` and `first` functions, with their `ignorenulls=True` flags, can be combined with the `rowsBetween` windowing. If we want to fill backwards, we select the first non-null that is between the current row and the end. If we want to fill forwards, we select the last non-null that is between the beginning and the current row.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
import sys

df.withColumn(
  'data',
  F.first(
    F.col('data'),
    ignorenulls=True
  ) \
    .over(
      W.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize)
    )
  )
```

source on filling in spark: https://towardsdatascience.com/end-to-end-time-series-interpolation-in-pyspark-filling-the-gap-5ccefc6b7fc9

Comment: The correct param is `ignorenulls` (`s` was missing)

Answer (score 4):

Actually backfill on distributed dataset is not as easy task as in pandas (local) dataframe - you cannot be sure that value to fill exists in the same partition. I would use crossJoin with windowing, for example fo DF:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('2017-01-01', None), 
    ('2017-01-02', 'B'), 
    ('2017-01-03', None), 
    ('2017-01-04', None), 
    ('2017-01-05', 'E'), 
    ('2017-01-06', None), 
    ('2017-01-07', 'G')], ['date', 'value'])
df.show()

+----------+-----+
|      date|value|
+----------+-----+
|2017-01-01| null|
|2017-01-02|    B|
|2017-01-03| null|
|2017-01-04| null|
|2017-01-05|    E|
|2017-01-06| null|
|2017-01-07|    G|
+----------+-----+
```

The code would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.alias('a').crossJoin(df.alias('b')) \
    .where((col('b.date') >= col('a.date')) & (col('a.value').isNotNull() | col('b.value').isNotNull())) \
    .withColumn('rn', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('a.date').orderBy('b.date'))) \
    .where(col('rn') == 1) \
    .select('a.date', coalesce('a.value', 'b.value').alias('value')) \
    .orderBy('a.date') \
    .show()

+----------+-----+
|      date|value|
+----------+-----+
|2017-01-01|    B|
|2017-01-02|    B|
|2017-01-03|    E|
|2017-01-04|    E|
|2017-01-05|    E|
|2017-01-06|    G|
|2017-01-07|    G|
+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Wow that's ugly (not your fault, just the verbosity of it). How would you do this if there were multiple columns? i.e. each column is a time series.

Comment: You will need to adapt the first `where` to reflect chronographical order, for example: `(col('b.date') >= col('a.date')) & (col('b.time') >= col('a.time'))`. Next, add both columns in `orderBy` inside window definition.

Comment: Ah so each column needs to be explicitly stated. That won't be useful for my use case unfortunately as there are thousands, and sometimes tens of thousands of columns that require processing.

Comment: Are these columns indexes or data you need to backfill? If you just use them as values there is simpler way. Can you update question with sample data?