# Get the previous row value using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a table like this.

```
Id   prod   val                   
1    0       0         
2    0       0         
3    1       1000         
4    0       0         
5    1       2000         
6    0       0          
7    0       0
```

I want to add a new column `new_val` and the condition for this column is, if `prod = 0`, then `new_val` should be from the preceding row where `prod = 1`.

If `prod = 1` it should have the same value as `val` column. How do I achieve this using spark sql?

```
Id   prod   val       new_val                 
1    0       0        1000            
2    0       0        1000             
3    1       1000     1000                
4    0       0        2000                         
5    1       2000     2000               
6    1       4000     4000             
7    1       3000     3000
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you may check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773520/pyspark-how-to-backfill-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy("id")

df = df.withColumn("new_val", F.when(F.col("prod") == 0, F.lag("val").over(w)).otherwise(F.col("val")))
```

What we are basically doing is using an if-else condition:

When `prod` == 0, take `lag` of `val` which is value of previous row (over a window that is ordered by `id` column), and if `prod` == 1, then we use the present value of the column.

Comment: Thank you. What if the previous value is also 0. I want to pull the first value from the preceding row where prod=1

Comment: That's difficult @Sujatha, I'll think about it. Give me some time

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive that with

```
val w = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df
  .withColumn("new_val", when($"prod" === 0, null).otherwise($"val"))
  .withColumn("new_val", first("new_val", ignoreNulls = true).over(w))
```

It first, creates new column with `null` values whenever value doesn't change:

```
+---+----+----+-------+
| id|prod| val|new_val|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  1|   0|   0|   null|
|  2|   0|   0|   null|
|  3|   1|1000|   1000|
|  4|   0|   0|   null|
|  5|   1|2000|   2000|
|  6|   1|4000|   4000|
|  7|   1|3000|   3000|
+---+----+----+-------+
```

And it replaces values with first non-null value in the following records

```
+---+----+----+-------+
| id|prod| val|new_val|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  1|   0|   0|   1000|
|  2|   0|   0|   1000|
|  3|   1|1000|   1000|
|  4|   0|   0|   2000|
|  5|   1|2000|   2000|
|  6|   1|4000|   4000|
|  7|   1|3000|   3000|
+---+----+----+-------+
```