# Is it possible to ignore null values when using LEAD window function in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, null, window-functions

My dataframe like this

```
id  value  date    
1   100    2017 
1   null   2016 
1   20     2015 
1   100    2014
```

I would like to get most recent previous value but ignoring null

```
id  value  date   recent value
1   100    2017    20
1   null   2016    20
1   20     2015   100
1   100    2014   null
```

Is there any way to ignore null values while using `lead` window function?

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to ignore null values when using lead window function in Spark

It is not.

> I would like to get most recent value but ignoring null

Just use [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@last(columnName:String,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (or `first`) with `ignoreNulls`:

> `def last(columnName: String, ignoreNulls: Boolean): Column`
>
> Aggregate function: returns the last value of the column in a group.
>
> The function by default returns the last values it sees. It will return the last non-null value it sees when ignoreNulls is set to true. If all values are null, then null is returned.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Some(100), 2017), (1, None, 2016), (1, Some(20), 2015), 
  (1, Some(100), 2014)
).toDF("id", "value", "date")

df.withColumn(
  "last_value",
   last("value", true).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date"))
).show

+---+-----+----+----------+                                                     
| id|value|date|last_value|
+---+-----+----+----------+
|  1|  100|2014|       100|
|  1|   20|2015|        20|
|  1| null|2016|        20|
|  1|  100|2017|       100|
+---+-----+----+----------+
```

Comment: I like to get the most recent previous value.I updated the post also. Sorry I was not clear before

Comment: what if "most recent" is exclusive of the present

Comment: answering my own q: in this case, you need use (in SQL) `over(partition by id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)`. not sure how to translate that to Scala

Comment: Following up again: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019847/pyspark-forward-fill-with-last-observation-for-a-dataframe which shows how to use `rangeBetween`

Answer (score 2):

**Spark 3.2+** provides `ignoreNulls` inside [`lead`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#lead(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset:Int,defaultValue:Any,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#lag(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset:Int,defaultValue:Any,ignoreNulls:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) in Scala.

> **lead**(e: Column, offset: Int, defaultValue: Any, ignoreNulls: Boolean): Column

> **lag**(e: Column, offset: Int, defaultValue: Any, ignoreNulls: Boolean): Column

---

Test input:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq[(Integer, Integer, Integer)](
    (1, 100, 2017),
    (1, null, 2016),
    (1, 20, 2015),
    (1, 100, 2014)
).toDF("id", "value", "date")
```

`lead`:

```scala
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("date"))
val df2 = df.withColumn("lead_val", lead($"value", 1, null, true).over(w))
df2.show()
// +---+-----+----+--------+
// | id|value|date|lead_val|
// +---+-----+----+--------+
// |  1|  100|2017|      20|
// |  1| null|2016|      20|
// |  1|   20|2015|     100|
// |  1|  100|2014|    null|
// +---+-----+----+--------+
```

`lag`:

```scala
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
val df2 = df.withColumn("lead_val", lag($"value", 1, null, true).over(w))
df2.show()
// +---+-----+----+--------+
// | id|value|date|lead_val|
// +---+-----+----+--------+
// |  1|  100|2014|    null|
// |  1|   20|2015|     100|
// |  1| null|2016|      20|
// |  1|  100|2017|      20|
// +---+-----+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps:

1. Create a table with non null values
2. Join on the original table

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Some(100), 2017),
  (1, None, 2016),
  (1, Some(20), 2015),
  (1, Some(100), 2014)
).toDF("id", "value", "date")

// Step 1
val filledDf = df
  .where($"value".isNotNull)
  .withColumnRenamed("value", "recent_value")

// Step 2
val window: WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("l.id", "l.date").orderBy($"r.date".desc)

val finalDf = df.as("l")
  .join(filledDf.as("r"), $"l.id" === $"r.id" && $"l.date" > $"r.date", "left")
  .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(window))
  .where($"rn" === 1)
  .select("l.id", "l.date", "value", "recent_value")

finalDf.orderBy($"date".desc).show

+---+----+-----+------------+
| id|date|value|recent_value|
+---+----+-----+------------+
|  1|2017|  100|          20|
|  1|2016| null|          20|
|  1|2015|   20|         100|
|  1|2014|  100|        null|
+---+----+-----+------------+
```