# Pandas ffill() equivalent in PySpark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe which has missing values in a row, and I use
`df.ffill(axis=1, inplace=True)` to perform the transformation using Pandas.

I want to understand what would be the PySpark equivalent way to achieve this. I have read about using Window functions but those work over the column axis.

**Example :**

Input :

| id | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 | NaN | NaN | 6 |
| B | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Output :

| id | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: ``df.fillna()``? [Spark-API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: You can find your answer in this thread I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019847/pyspark-forward-fill-with-last-observation-for-a-dataframe

Comment: @seghairtarek As you can see, the requirement in that question was to perform forward filling on a column, whereas I need to perform the same on a row instead.
Updating my question to add example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` it will take values from `value3` column if it's not `null`, otherwise from `value2` column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

df = df.withColumn('value3', coalesce('value3', 'value2'))
```

To do this for all your dataset you simply do a for loop on all the columns. Like this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

cols = df.columns
for i in range(1,len(cols)):
    df = df.withColumn(cols[i], coalesce(cols[i], cols[i-1]))
```