# Using PySpark, Incrementing frequency in data, for a specific number?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset like:

```
a   
c   
c   
d   
b   
a   
a   
d   
d   
c
c   
b   
a   
b
```

I want to add a column that looks like the one below. When 'c' is reached, the new column will be zero and then be increased by one. Is there a way we can do this using pyspark?

```
a   1
c   0
c   0
d   2
b   2
a   2
a   2
d   2
d   2
c   0
c   0
b   3
a   3
b   3
```

I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lag, sum

s = df.filter(col("col") == 'c')
df = df.withColumn("new", when(s.neq(lag("s", 1).over()), sum("s").over(Window.orderBy("index"))).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: Please add your code for the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses [PySpark SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html) to implement the logic requested above.

**Set-Up**

Create a DataFrame to mimic the example provided

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a',),
     ('c',),
     ('c',),
     ('d',),
     ('b',),
     ('a',),
     ('a',),
     ('d',),
     ('d',),
     ('c',),
     ('c',),
     ('b',),
     ('a',),
     ('b',),],
    ['id',])
```

Output

```
+---+
|id |
+---+
|a  |
|c  |
|c  |
|d  |
|b  |
|a  |
|a  |
|d  |
|d  |
|c  |
|c  |
|b  |
|a  |
|b  |
+---+
```

**Logic**

1. Calculate row number (reference logic for row_num [here](https://#%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe))

```
df = df.withColumn("row_num",  F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))
```

2. Use row number to determine the preceding id value (the lag). There is no preceding id for the first row so the lag results in a null - set this missing value to "c".

```
df = df.withColumn("lag_id", F.lag("id",1).over(Window.orderBy("row_num")))
df = df.na.fill(value="c", subset=['lag_id'])
```

output

```
+---+--------------+------+
|id | row_num      |lag_id|
+---+--------------+------+
|a  |1             |c     |
|c  |2             |a     |
|c  |3             |c     |
|d  |4             |c     |
|b  |5             |d     |
|a  |6             |b     |
|a  |7             |a     |
|d  |8             |a     |
|d  |9             |d     |
|c  |10            |d     |
|c  |11            |c     |
|b  |12            |c     |
|a  |13            |b     |
|b  |14            |a     |
+---+--------------+------+
```

3. Determine order (`sequence`) for rows that immediately follow a row where id = "c"

```
df_sequence = df.filter((df.id != "c") & (df.lag_id == "c"))
df_sequence = df_sequence.withColumn("sequence", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("row_num")))
```

output

```
+---+--------------+------+--------+
|id | row_num      |lag_id|sequence|
+---+--------------+------+--------+
|a  |1             |c     |1       |
|d  |4             |c     |2       |
|b  |12            |c     |3       |
+---+--------------+------+--------+
```

4. Join the sequence DF to the original DF

```
df_joined = df.alias("df1").join(df_sequence.alias("df2"),
                                on="row_num",
                                how="leftouter")\
                          .select(df["*"],df_sequence["sequence"])
                                )
```

5. Set `sequence` to 0 when `id` = "c"

```
df_joined = df_joined.withColumn('sequence', F.when(df_joined.id == "c", 0)
                                              .otherwise(df_joined.sequence)
```

output

```
+---+--------------+------+--------+
|id | row_num      |lag_id|sequence|
+---+--------------+------+--------+
|a  |1             |c     |1       |
|c  |2             |a     |0       |
|c  |3             |c     |0       |
|d  |4             |c     |2       |
|b  |5             |d     |null    |
|a  |6             |b     |null    |
|a  |7             |a     |null    |
|d  |8             |a     |null    |
|d  |9             |d     |null    |
|c  |10            |d     |0       |
|c  |11            |c     |0       |
|b  |12            |c     |3       |
|a  |13            |b     |null    |
|b  |14            |a     |null    |
+---+--------------+------+--------+
```

6. Forward fill sequence values (reference the forward fill logic [here](https://#%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019847/pyspark-forward-fill-with-last-observation-for-a-dataframe))

```
df_final = df_joined.withColumn('sequence', F.last('sequence', ignorenulls=True).over(Window.orderBy("row_num")
```

**Final Output**

```
+---+--------------+------+--------+
|id | row_num      |lag_id|sequence|
+---+--------------+------+--------+
|a  |1             |c     |1       |
|c  |2             |a     |0       |
|c  |3             |c     |0       |
|d  |4             |c     |2       |
|b  |5             |d     |2       |
|a  |6             |b     |2       |
|a  |7             |a     |2       |
|d  |8             |a     |2       |
|d  |9             |d     |2       |
|c  |10            |d     |0       |
|c  |11            |c     |0       |
|b  |12            |c     |3       |
|a  |13            |b     |3       |
|b  |14            |a     |3       |
+---+--------------+------+--------+
```