# What's the time complexity of forward filling and backward filling in spark?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, data-processing

**My question: Need to understand the time complexity of dynamic forward filling and back filling in spark**
Hello, I have a scala job that reads Delta Table A, transforms Data Frame and writes to Delta Table B (empty table)

The job runs processes 94,356,726 records and finishes in 16 minutes.

However, after adding dynamic filling logic to the Dataframe transform, the job executes for **2 hours and 20 minutes.**

What's a big gap in performance, what's the time complexity of the backfilling?

**Details**
***Purpose of the backfilling***

***I have data like this:***

| id | version | data_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | null |
| 0 | 3 | "test 2" |
| 0 | 2 | null |
| 0 | 1 | "test 1" |

***I want to get the data like this:***

| id | version | data_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | "test 2"// filled from version 3 |
| 0 | 3 | "test 2" |
| 0 | 2 | "test 1" // filled from version 2 |
| 0 | 1 | "test 1" |

***My method***
Following method here: [Pyspark : forward fill with last observation for a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019847/pyspark-forward-fill-with-last-observation-for-a-dataframe)

```scala
// before using backfilling, the job uses the "partitionWindow " for dedup
val partitionWindow = Window
  .partitionBy("id")
  .orderBy(desc("version"), desc("timestamp'))

val backfillWindow = partitionWindow
  .rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn("data_filled", coalesce(first("data_column", true).over(backfillWindow), col("data_column")))
```

***My Observation***

- Execution time: It works as expected, but huge performance downgrade, from 16 minutes
  to 2hours and 20 minutes
- Spark stage: In spark history server, the bottleneck is
  the "Delta Lake touching files: low shuffle merge", gap is 1.8 minute
  vs. 1.1 hours
- Physical plan: I use winmerge to compare the physical plan of the "Delta Lake touching files: low shuffle merge" stage, between 2 jobs, no big difference
- I check [pyspark ffill and bfill](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), they shall have similar time complexity, the doc doesn't mention time complexity, only says: " Avoid this method against very large dataset."

***More Thoughts:***
I'm doing one-direction backfilling, it shall be close to O(Nlog(N)), right? Maybe a bi-directional filling (forward and backward at the same time) would be different

Thank you!