# Forward Filling Multiple Columns Reusable Function Code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert my forward fill imputing process based off a previous stack-overflow post to a reusable function (something with `def(...)`) so I can apply it to multiple columns instead of having a code snippet for each column. Creating reusable functions with parameters has always been a challenge for me.

Thanks!

Post => [Forward fill missing values in Spark/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131982/forward-fill-missing-values-in-spark-python?rq=1)

Code Example Snippet

```py
# sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-05-10 7:30:05', '10', '0.5'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'UNKNOWN', '0.24'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:15', '6', 'UNKNOWN'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:20', '7', 'UNKNOWN'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:25', '10', '1.1'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:30', 'UNKNOWN', '1.1'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:35', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:49', '50', 'UNKNOWN')], ["date", "v1", "v2"])

df = df.withColumn("date", F.col("date").cast("timestamp"))

# schema
root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- v1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v2: string (nullable = true)

# imputer process / all cols that need filled are strings
def stringReplaceFunc(x, y):
    '''
    this function replaces column values:
    ex: replace 'UNKNOWN' reading with nulls for forward filling function
    : x => source col
    : y => replace value
    '''
    return F.when(x != y, x).otherwise(F.lit(None)) # replace with NULL

# this windows function triggers forward filling for null values created from StringReplaceFunc
window = Window\
.partitionBy(F.month("date"))\
.orderBy('date')\
.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)

# here is where I am trying to make a function so I don't have to code each col that needs filled individually
df = df\
.withColumn("v1", stringReplaceFunc(F.col("v1"), "UNKNOWN"))

fill_v1 = F.last(df['v1'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
df = df.withColumn('v1',  fill_v1)

df = df\
.withColumn("v2", stringReplaceFunc(F.col("v2"), "UNKNOWN"))

fill_v1 = F.last(df['v2'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
df = df.withColumn('v2',  fill_v1)

# imputing results of the output needed
df.show()

+-------------------+---+----+
|               date| v1|  v2|
+-------------------+---+----+
|2019-05-10 07:30:05| 10| 0.5|
|2019-05-10 07:30:10| 10|0.24|
|2019-05-10 07:30:15|  6|0.24|
|2019-05-10 07:30:20|  7|0.24|
|2019-05-10 07:30:25| 10| 1.1|
|2019-05-10 07:30:30| 10| 1.1|
|2019-05-10 07:30:35| 10| 1.1|
|2019-05-10 07:30:49| 50| 1.1|
+-------------------+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% that I understood the question correctly but this a way to enclose the code you mentioned into a python function:

```py
def forward_fill(df, col_name):
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, stringReplaceFunc(F.col(col_name), "UNKNOWN"))

    last_func = F.last(df[col_name], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
    df = df.withColumn(col_name,  last_func)
    return df
```

Then you can call it as: `df = forward_fill(df, 'v1')`

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to find a solution via for loop with nested function.

Comment: Perfect then :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that is working

```py
def stringReplaceFunc(x, y):
    return F.when(x != y, x).otherwise(F.lit(None)) # replace with NULL

def forwardFillImputer(df, cols=[], partitioner="date", value="UNKNOWN"):
  for i in cols:
    window = Window\
    .partitionBy(F.month(partitioner))\
    .orderBy(partitioner)\
    .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)
    df = df\
    .withColumn(i, stringReplacer(F.col(i), value))
    fill = F.last(df[i], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
    df = df.withColumn(i,  fill)
  return df
df = forwardFillImputer(df, cols=[i for i in df.columns])
```