# Insert missing elements in list as Rows per Time-Window group to DataFrame

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to figure this out pro-grammatically ... seems like a difficult problem ... basically if sensor item is not captured in time-series timestamp interval source data then want to append a row for each missing sensor item with a NULL value per timestamp window

```py
# list of sensor items [have 300 plus; only showing 4 as example]
list = ["temp", "pressure", "vacuum", "burner"]

# sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'temp', '99'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:05', 'burner', 'TRUE'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'vacuum', '.15'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'burner', 'FALSE'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:10', 'temp', '75'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:15', 'temp', '77'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:20', 'pressure', '.22'),\
                            ('2019-05-10 7:30:20', 'temp', '101'),], ["date", "item", "value"])
```

```py
# current dilemma => all sensor items are not being captured / only updates to sensors are being captured in current back-end design streaming devices
+------------------+--------+-----+
|              date|    item|value|
+------------------+--------+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|    temp|   99|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|  burner| TRUE|

|2019-05-10 7:30:10|  vacuum|  .15|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|  burner|FALSE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|    temp|   75|

|2019-05-10 7:30:15|    temp|   77|

|2019-05-10 7:30:20|pressure|  .22|
|2019-05-10 7:30:20|    temp|  101|
+------------------+--------+-----+
```

Want to capture every sensor item per timestamp so forward filling imputing can performed prior to pivoting data-frame [forward filling on 300 plus cols is causing scala errors =>

[Spark Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError Window Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368747/spark-caused-by-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-window-function/56369342?noredirect=1#comment99379550_56369342])

```py
# desired output
+------------------+--------+-----+
|              date|    item|value|
+------------------+--------+-----+
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|    temp|   99|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|  burner| TRUE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|  vacuum| NULL|
|2019-05-10 7:30:05|pressure| NULL|

|2019-05-10 7:30:10|  vacuum|  .15|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|  burner|FALSE|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|    temp|   75|
|2019-05-10 7:30:10|pressure| NULL|

|2019-05-10 7:30:15|    temp|   77|
|2019-05-10 7:30:15|pressure| NULL|
|2019-05-10 7:30:15|  burner| NULL|
|2019-05-10 7:30:15|  vacuum| NULL|

|2019-05-10 7:30:20|pressure|  .22|
|2019-05-10 7:30:20|    temp|  101|
|2019-05-10 7:30:20|  vacuum| NULL|
|2019-05-10 7:30:20|  burner| NULL|
+------------------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Here's an idea (not sure how efficient). Create a temp dataframe as with the crossJoin of the distinct dates and dataframe of all of your items: `df.select('date').distinct().crossJoin(broadcast(spark.createDataFrame([('temp',), ('burner',), ('vacuum',), ('pressure',)], ["item"])))`. Now do a right join of your original dataframe to this temp one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484277/insert-missing-elements-in-list-as-rows-per-time-window-group-to-dataframe#comment99559036_56484277):

You can right join your DataFrame with the Cartesian product of the distinct dates and the `sensor_list`. Since the `sensor_list` is small, you can [`broadcast`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.broadcast) it.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

sensor_list = ["temp", "pressure", "vacuum", "burner"]

df.join(
    df.select('date')\
        .distinct()\
        .crossJoin(broadcast(spark.createDataFrame([(x,) for x in sensor_list], ["item"]))),
    on=["date", "item"],
    how="right"
).sort("date", "item").show()
#+------------------+--------+-----+
#|              date|    item|value|
#+------------------+--------+-----+
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|  burner| TRUE|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|pressure| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|    temp|   99|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:05|  vacuum| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|  burner|FALSE|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|pressure| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|    temp|   75|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:10|  vacuum|  .15|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:15|  burner| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:15|pressure| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:15|    temp|   77|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:15|  vacuum| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:20|  burner| null|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:20|pressure|  .22|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:20|    temp|  101|
#|2019-05-10 7:30:20|  vacuum| null|
#+------------------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense!  thank you very much!  i will give it a shot on the large data set and let you know how it goes.

Comment: this join method is working out pretty well ... since it is broadcast no shuffle is happening so the performance looks to be feasible.  thanks!

Comment: i sort of spoke too soon ... performance is still ok however ```explain plan``` is showing ```nestedBroadcastLoopJoin``` which I have heard horror stories about ... any insights?