# Fill null or empty with next Row value with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to replace null values in spark data frame with next row not null value. There is additional row_count column added for windows partitioning and ordering. More specifically, I'd like to achieve the following result:

```
      +---------+-----------+      +---------+--------+
      | row_count |       id|      |row_count |     id|
      +---------+-----------+      +------+-----------+
      |        1|       null|      |     1|        109|
      |        2|        109|      |     2|        109|
      |        3|       null|      |     3|        108|
      |        4|       null|      |     4|        108|
      |        5|        108| =>   |     5|        108|
      |        6|       null|      |     6|        110|
      |        7|        110|      |     7|        110|
      |        8|       null|      |     8|       null|
      |        9|       null|      |     9|       null|
      |       10|       null|      |    10|       null|
      +---------+-----------+      +---------+--------+
```

I tried with below code, It is not giving proper result.

```
      val ss = dataframe.select($"*", sum(when(dataframe("id").isNull||dataframe("id") === "", 1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.orderBy($"row_count")) as "value")
      val window1=Window.partitionBy($"value").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(0, Long.MaxValue)
      val selectList=ss.withColumn("id_fill_from_below",last("id").over(window1)).drop($"row_count").drop($"value")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark / Scala: forward fill with last observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621319/spark-scala-forward-fill-with-last-observation)

Comment: @ user10938362 this is a different one. In this fill null with First value. means in this used first_value feature of the window function. In this solution fill data top to down but we need to fill data down to top.

Comment: you can change the order of your data to row_count desc then apply the solution from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621319/spark-scala-forward-fill-with-last-observation

Comment: I have added a solution using only window functions in another SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876725/2166220

Comment: https://johnpaton.net/posts/forward-fill-spark/
This post helped me. This was the best solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a approach

1. Filter the non nulls (dfNonNulls)
2. Filter the nulls (dfNulls)
3. Find the right value for null id, using join and Window function
4. Fill the null dataframe (dfNullFills)
5. union dfNonNulls and dfNullFills

data.csv

```
row_count,id
1,
2,109
3,
4,
5,108
6,
7,110
8,
9,
10,
```

```
var df = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("data.csv")

var dfNulls = df.filter(
  $"id".isNull
).withColumnRenamed(
  "row_count","row_count_nulls"
).withColumnRenamed(
  "id","id_nulls"
)

val dfNonNulls = df.filter(
  $"id".isNotNull
).withColumnRenamed(
  "row_count","row_count_values"
).withColumnRenamed(
  "id","id_values"
)

dfNulls = dfNulls.join(
  dfNonNulls, $"row_count_nulls" lt $"row_count_values","left"
).select(
  $"id_nulls",$"id_values",$"row_count_nulls",$"row_count_values"
)

val window = Window.partitionBy("row_count_nulls").orderBy("row_count_values")

val dfNullFills = dfNulls.withColumn(
  "rn", row_number.over(window)
).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn").select(
  $"row_count_nulls".alias("row_count"),$"id_values".alias("id"))

dfNullFills .union(dfNonNulls).orderBy($"row_count").show()
```

which results in

```
+---------+----+
|row_count|  id|
+---------+----+
|        1| 109|
|        2| 109|
|        3| 108|
|        4| 108|
|        5| 108|
|        6| 110|
|        7| 110|
|        8|null|
|        9|null|
|       10|null|
+---------+----+
```